# Responsive and Full-height sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### The idea

Just like facebook modals, but this one have to be responsive.

In this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Frondor/ufby12n7/5/embedded/result/ (resize/adjust the result's window to see the *responsibility*).

I'm placing a description next to a video, the desc. is inside the sidebar, but it's too short and **when the window is wide enough**, sidebar (`.sideview`) have to hit the bottom of the whole modal anyway.

So I've absolute positioned it and used the "`top:0; right:0; bottom:0;`" trick: **http://jsfiddle.net/Frondor/ufby12n7/8/**

It worked like a charm, but when the window's size goes smaller, the `.sideview`is overlapping the video, instead of moving to its bottom like happened in the [previous version](http://jsfiddle.net/Frondor/ufby12n7/5/).

### The code

I'm using bootstrap grid system like this:

```
<div class="mmcontainer row">

        <div class="viewer col-sm-8">
              <!-- here goes video -->
        </div>

        <div class="sideview col-sm-4">
              <!-- here goes the video desc.-->
        </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.mmcontainer {
    background: #333;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    margin: 30px;
}
.viewer {
    color: #666;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
    padding:10px;
}
.sideview {
    background: #ccc;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #EEE;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 250px; 
    max-height: 400px;
    position: absolute; /* here's the trick */
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-y: auto; /* because scrollbars are awesome */
}
```

### The "behavior" I want to achieve:

- When the description is too short, and the window wide enough: Just
  continue `.sideview` background until modal's bottom.
- When the description is too long, and the window wide enough: there
  should be a vertical scrollbar in the `.sideview`.
- When the window is small enough, the `.sideview` should be placed
  just below the `.viewer`.

This is driving me crazy! So, if there's somebody who knows how to deal with this kind of things, It'll be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this http://jsfiddle.net/ufby12n7/9/

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
    .sideview {
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to end up with a media query, but this is working really nice. Thank you Bojan!